# Python "Arrays and Restrictions"

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

QUESTION:
Write the python code which does the following:

For a given array of positive numbers perform the following action:

1. a) Create a new array and copy the number from the first array to
   the    second array without copying the repeating numbers. (Second
   array       elements should be unique)

   b) While creating second array place additional -1 integer for every 3 numbers that’s been added to the array. (After copying `5, 6, 7` from first array second array contents should be `5, 6, 7, -1`)
2. After creating second array print it to console in a way that every
   row will have only 3 elements of the second array.

Restrictions:

1. You are not allowed to use `while` loops.
2. You are not allowed to use `[` and `]` character in you code except for initialization of first and second array at the beginning of your code.

**Example**:

**Input**:

```
[5, 3, 20, 7, 32, 5, 2, 4, 19, 5, 45, 1, 7, 3, 2, 9, 5, 7, 6, 27, 74 ]
```

**Resulting Array**:

```
[5, 3, 20, -1, 7, 32, 2, -1, 4, 19, 45, -1, 1, 9, 6, -1, 27, 74]
```

**output**:

```
5 3 20

7 32 2

4 19 45

1 9 6

27 74
```

**MY WORK:**

```
A=[5,3,20,7,32,5,2,4,19,5,45,1,7,3,2,9,5,7,6,27,74]
B=[]
counter=0
n=1
for i in A:
    if i not in B:
        B.append(i)
        counter+=1
    if counter==3*n:
        B.append(-1)
        n+=1
print(B)
```

That is what i am getting as an output:

```
[5, 3, 20, -1, 7, 32, 2, -1, 4, 19, 45, -1, 1, 9, 6, -1, 27, 74]
```

I don't know how to print output as what they want without using brackets `[]`. 
I hope you can help me somehow.

Comment: Try writing something which begins with `for i in B:`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close! You just need to add another `for` loop in order to print your elements:

If `i == -1` you print a new line to seperate these, if not you print the contents of the list `B` separated by `end=" "` (space character):

```
for i in B:
    if i == -1:
        # prints a new line character
        # print("\n") if you need a blank line between entries 
        print()
    else: 
        # end specifies how your elements will be seperated
        print(i, end=" ")
```

Using your input, this prints:

```
5 3 20 
7 32 2 
4 19 45 
1 9 6 
27 74
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over arrays (and any other iterable) in Python by value in a simple for loop, thus

```
for element in B:
    if element == -1:
        print #this will just print new line marker
    else:
        print element, #notice the comma - it will not add new line marker
```

will print elements of your `B` container in a row, with new lines on `-1` elements.

**Print semantics used here assumes Python 2.X**. If you are using Python 3.X then you need to change them to appropriate statements which prints new line `print()`  and the one which does not `print(element, end=' ')`

Comment: OP might be using Python 3.